What kind of problem am I trying to solve?
I have 500 locations that have multiple skus with varying quantities and I have 6000 orders requesting multiple skus with varying quantities.
I have to minimize the total number of locations I visit(distance does not matter in this case)
An extra constraint is that I can only fulfill 600 orders per batch/round/at a time.
Dynamic programming of combinations seems to cause the search space to explode (I am probably not pruning the branches correctly) Greedy search seems to works fine for the first part but I am wondering how I can approximate a better answer. I am kinda stumped by the constraint as well.
I checked the locations and it seems like an average sku sits in 3 locations and 12 locations at most. There are about 12000 unique skus.
It feels like a covering/packing problem but none of them seems quite right for my case.
What kind of problem is this and what direction should I take on solving it? Or better yet is there a straightforward alogrithm to this problem that I am not seeing?

Can you handle orders in any order?  Or do you have to take the first 600 first?

If every SKU is in 3 locations, then a 3-approximation is to visit all location containing a given SKU.

So the problem is to select a minimum-size set of locations such that for every SKU the total number at the selected locations is at least the total number required by the orders?


Any order you want but the 600 orders must be fulfilled before you move to fulfilling other orders.
Yes but the 600 orders constraint stumps me.


Your problem seems to be a generalized case of Set-Multicover problem (a generalization of the classic Set-Cover). Which makes your problem NP-Hard [a formal proof is left for your exercise].
Given your problem is NP-Hard, you can use some greedy, heuristic-based branch and bound or approximation algorithms. Formulating an integer linear program (ILP) can also help since modern ILP solvers have become very efficient. Formulating an ILP can also help in using techniques from the optimization theory world.
